# Proving Cantor's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}$From *Problem-Solvers Topology*

> Prove the following:
>
> **CANTOR'S THEOREM**
>
> If $A$ is a set, then $$\card A < \card \mathcal{P}(A)$$
>
> where $\card A$ stands for the cardinality of set $A$.

**My Answer**

If $A = \emptyset$, then $\card A =0$ and $\card \mathcal{P}(A)=1$.

If $A = \{a\}$, then $\card A=1$ and $\card \mathcal{P}(A)=2$.

So suppose that $A$ has at least two elements.

Define a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $f(x) = \{x\}$ for all $x \in A$.

Then $f$ is injective. But it cannot be surjective, because for any two distinct elements $a,b \in A$, there is no element in $A$ that is sent to the set $\{a,b\}$ in $\mathcal{P}(A)$. Therefore, there is no bijection, and $\card A < \card\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Do you think my answer is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to assume that there is a surjection from A to P(A), and then show that this leads to a contradiction. Since the function f you defined is injective, you have shown that $card(A)\le card(P(A))$.

Comment: @oldrinb I saw your edit but I'm not really sure how I can accept it. I thought it would be accepted automatically...

Comment: Your proof, as others have noted, is not correct. You have to prove the statement that there is no surjection from $A$ to $P(A)$. To prove this, you can suppose there is one, and based on that derive a contradiction. The slick way to prove this is suppose you have a surjection $f : A \rightarrow P(A)$, and consider the set $S = \{ x : x \notin f(x)\}$ (note that $f(x)$ is a set, as it is an element of $P(A)$, the set of all sets). Now consider the cases $x \in S$ and $x \notin S$ seperately.

Comment: @user84413: Or slightly more constructively, you consider an arbitrary function and show that it is not surjective.

Comment: @oldrinb I think your edit was automatically rejected because I was editing it at the same time (to change the tag.)

Comment: For example there is an injection $\phi$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(x)=x$. This is not a surjection. Yet $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same cardinality. Your proof works for finite sets.

Comment: I see you've "accepted" an answer.  My answer contains some information beyond what that one has, so you might see what you can learn from it too.

Comment: The argument works when the cardinality of the set is at least $2$, since, when the set is finite, it is enough to show that there is an injection that is not a bijection.  If the cardinality is $0$ or $1$, then the mapping defined in the argument fails to have $\varnothing$ as one of its values, so that works.  With infinite sets, the argument still shows there is an injection that is not a bijection, but with infinite sets, that is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument works when the set is finite, provided one relies on some simple facts about finite sets.

Infinite sets can behave differently. There can be two injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ that both fail to be surjective.  That cannot happen with finite sets.  (For example, Let $A$ be the interval $[-1,1]$ and let $B$ be the interval $(-1,1)$.  Then for $x\in A$ let $f(x)=x/2$, and for $x\in B$ let $g(x)=x$.  Both are injective; neither is surjective).

Or for $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$, let $f(x)=x^2$.  Then $f$ is an injection from this set into itself that is not surjective, and yet a bijection from this set to itself exists (many such bijections exist).

A standard proof of Cantor's theorem (that is not a proof by contradiction, but contains a proof by contradiction within it) goes like this: Let $f$ be any injection from $A$ into the set of all subsets of $A$.  Consider the set
$$
C=\{x\in A: x\not\in f(x)\}.
$$
Then prove by contradiction that there is no $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=C$.  (I leave the details of this part as an exercise.)

Note: I did not say which function $f$ is.  Therefore this applies to ALL functions from $A$ to the power-set of $A$ that are injective.  So ALL of them fail to be surjective.

Comment: No, the given argument doesn't work. It only works for the empty set and singletons.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure why that would be wrong...there is a similar argument here http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/cantorth.htm right? And also in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)...

Comment: @Artus: No. There are arguments by induction for finite sets. But the argument **in your question** is not an argument by induction. It's an argument which is entirely incorrect, except for the two cases that you handle separately for $\varnothing$ and singletons. Saying that your argument "works when the set is finite" is plain wrong. Also, I'm not saying that the proof is false. Had you been asking for a proof of the theorem I would have probably voted to close this as a duplicate, because the proof has been posted many times on the site before.

Comment: @Artus: [cont'd] You ask about the correctness of your argument. I, and also Trevor, answered that. The user snarski in the comments gave the outline of the correct proof of the general case. All in all, I found no reason to add something like that to my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't really see any induction argument in the first link that I gave (or in wikipedia for that matter). Also, I wasn't really trying to use induction in my argument...I was just using cases. I just showed the first two cases, because I wanted to assume that there were at least two elements in the other sets that I was about to prove.

Comment: @Artus: No, I apologize. I thought that it was a link that I knew which had an inductive proof for the finite case, this was in sync because I was talking about the mistake in the first line of this answer; and claiming it *does* work for finite sets, would somehow assume it was pertaining an inductive proof or so. In either case my qualms are not that Michael posted the proof (even though it was posted on the site more than several times before); it's the fact that he claims your argument is correct for every finite set which is blatantly false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : When the cardinality is at least $2$, the argument as stated correctly shows there is an injection that is not a bijection.  With finite sets, it's enough to show there is an injection that is not a bijection.  Only when the set is infinite is that not enough.

Comment: Michael, yes you are right. I'm sorry, I had a terrible day yesterday. I removed the comment form the question stating that your answer is wrong. I will point out, however, that when I was TA'ing intro to logic and set theory the statement that only finite sets have this property "If there is a bijection, then every injection is a bijection" is very non-trivial to use and understand. From the question itself it was impossible to conclude that the OP knows or doesn't know this sort of fact, and I assumed the latter.

Answer (score 9):

You only proved that there is a function that is not a surjection $A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$, not that there is no function that is a surjection $A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Answer (score 7):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}$No. Your answer is not correct. Between any two sets (both having two elements or more) there is a non-surjective map. Your task is to show that **every** set $A$ and **every** function from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$ is not surjective.

To clarify the point you're missing, the argument in your proof amounts to the following "proof":

> **"Theorem"**: There is no bijection between $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.
>
> *"Proof"*. Consider the function $f(0)=f(1)=2$. It is clearly not surjective, therefore it is not a bijection. And therefore $\card(\{0,1\})\neq\card(\{2,3\})$.